# IBM MobileFirst: Build scripts for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, build-script

Are there any standard build scripts (For building adapters and Hybrid Apps) that I can use as base for creating my build process.

Thanks in advance!

/Amit

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst Platform does not officially support Jenkins and thus does not provide any 'standard build scripts'.

It could be that some customers would prefer to use Jenkins over other tools and methods.

The MFP user documentation suggests and provide instructions for using Apache Ant.